# Unable to connect to ODBC data source when running application from another PC

Tags: c#-4.0, odbc

I have an application, that when running off my main computer, works fine, but when i attempt to run the application off my laptop, the connection to the database fails. Its using this connection string :

```
Dsn=XAMPP;description=USB Server;server=localhost;uid=root;database=mod_manager;port=3306
```

When i attempt to connect i get the message:

```
Data source name not found and no default driver specified
```

is there a specific .dll that i must include with the executable?

EDIT:

I have tried installing the ODBC driver supplied by oracle, and also tried packaging all the .dlls related to the .exe file. Also tested it on a 3rd computer, this one running windows 7, as my laptop was running win8, and my main pc is running 7. Still getting the error. I appears my main PC has something that the others do not...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the ODBC Control panel and check you have created a DSN called XAMPP, thats what the connection string is telling the driver manager to look for and its reporting back it can't find it.